# How do I show Doctrine 2 queries in the Silex debug toolbar?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, silex

When using Silex, how can I get Doctrine queries to show up in the web toolbar?

I'm using `Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider` and `Dflydev\Silex\Provider\DoctrineOrm\DoctrineOrmServiceProvider`.

I also have **"symfony/doctrine-bridge": "v2.4.1"** enabled in composer.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a service provider that already does that, like https://github.com/saxulum/saxulum-webprofiler-provider